# How to eject global onerror handler into <img> tags in react, to capture broken links?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

Thanks for your time.

I'd like to automatic detect broken image links in react, and send error reports via sentry.

Here are some solutions I've thought about, but none of them is perfect for me.

## 1 Manually add onerror handler to every `<img>` tag

It works, but too complex, and maybe forgotten in the future.

## 2 Add `onerror` handler to all `<img>` tags once a time

Using jQuery or document.getElementsByTagName("img") to find all img tags, and eject `onerror` handler to them.

This sounds simple, but may not work? Because if run this code in index.html, react tags may have not rendered yet; if run this code in componentDidMount / componentDidUpdate，then`<img>` tags already loaded.

## 3 Automatic eject `onerror` handler to `<img>` tags in webpack

This may be the best solution, just do a string replace, use `<img onerror="xxx">` instead of `<img>`, but regex match is too complex, I can't replace code like `console.log('<img>')`.

Is there a webpack plugin can do this work? Or is there a webpack plugin already parsed jsx source to tags, then I can just eject `onerror` attributes to all `<img>` tags? Or is there a better solution?

Thanks again!

PS:

There are react components can do this work, just like @varun's answer. But it seems too big a thing to replace all `<img>` tags just to find broken links, I'd like to find a better solution.

Thanks all the same, @varun

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react, might as well create an `ErrorImage` component, which defines an `image` in its render function and handle the error.

Comment: Actually, there are components like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image, but replace all `<img>` tags to '<ReactImage >' is also too heavy a thing, I'd like to do this without change my code.